# finding chains in graphs using python networkx module

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph with nodes and edges list

```
nodes=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'] 
G.add_edges_from ([('a','f'),('a','d'),('a','b'),('a','e'),('b','g'),
                   ('b','e'),('b','c'),('c','b'),('c','d'),('d','a'),
                   ('d','c'),('e','b'),('e','a'),  ('f','a'),('g','b')].
```

my question is to identify the neighbors of each node, which I identified using `G.neighbors(node[i])`

and I got the result as

```
a=>['e', 'b', 'f', 'd']
b=>['e', 'c', 'g', 'a']
c=>['b', 'd']
d=>['c', 'a']
e=>['b', 'a']
f=>['a']
g=>['b'].
```

now I have to sort the chain as `f <=d <=b` and another chain as `g<=c<=a` which means order them as subsets of another. f is a subset of d which is a subset of b like that.

`e` is the central node connecting these two chains,which I have calculated manually. The problem is I am not getting this chain, how to loop them?

Comment: Please use appropriate code markings to make it more readable, please.

Comment: To be clear: does "f is a subset of d which is a subset of b" mean "the neighbors of f form a subset of the neighbors of d which is a subset of the neighbors of b"?

Comment: hai joel, yes i mean neighbors of f is a subset of neighbors of d, whose neighbors are present in neighbors of b.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to list all nodes which are subset of each others in terms of neighbors. Thus, for you sample graph the chains should be:

f <=d <=b, g<=c<=a (which you mentioned) plus g<=e which you have not mentioned. I assumed you do not want to have subsets of already existing chains; store g<=c<=a but not c<=a

That was my solution for solving your problem (I commented it to make it as clear as possible):

```
tmp = [] # temporary storage for chains
chains = [] # stores all found chains
nodes = G.nodes() # save the labels of nodes
prev_node =  None # Holds the node which other nodes will be checked if they are a subset of.
for i in xrange(len(nodes)): # each node is considered as a superset and others will be compared to it
    tmp.append(nodes[i]) # append this node as the head of the chain
    prev_node = nodes[i] # store it to compare other nodes to it
    for j in xrange (i+1,len(nodes)): # looping the rest of the nodes
        if set(G.neighbors(nodes[j])).issubset(set(((G.neighbors(prev_node))))) : # if it is a subset
            tmp.append(nodes[j]) # append to the chain
            prev_node = nodes[j] # store to check if the rest of the nodes are subset of this one

    if not (is_subset(chains,tmp)): # After finishing the chain check it is not a subset of an already created chain
        chains.append(list(reversed(tmp))) # add it to the chains
    tmp =[] # reset
    prev_node = None
print chains
```

The is_subset function is a simple function that returns true if tmp is already a subset of chains (to exclude it):

```
def is_subset(chains,tmp):
    for i in xrange(len(chains)):
        if set(tmp).issubset(chains[i]):
                return True
    return False
```